# Apostrophe Workflow: Find Draft / Live Documents

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Exploring `apostrophe-worflow`, I wonder how to search `draft` or `live` version of my document using `self.apos.myModule.find(...)` with an option.

EDIT: My use case is task, so, there is no current locale, so, I suppose the default locale will be taken.

I know I need some change in current code but, I want to know how to detect a "weird" behaviour and I need to know how `workflow` works.

Beside this, this question is also extend to which locale is return for a `.insert` or `.update` function.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find(...).workflowLocale('default')` or `.find(...).workflowLocale('default-draft')`, for instance. Append `-draft` to any locale name to get the draft content instead, remove it to get the live content... etc.

The default of course is to fetch documents for the current locale.

Comment: Great! I have edited the question but the response still great! Just I want to complete it with what is the current locale in a task? I suppose the default locale so ;)

Comment: Great question. Currently you would need to address that like this:

`apos.tasks.getReq({ locale: 'default-draft' })`

As our unit tests do.

But I see there's a limitation here which we should think about. The apostrophe-workflow module really should add a command line argument to Apostrophe for specifying a locale at startup.